# Tell a VBA function to update based on cells other than those in the arguments?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a function like below.

```
Public Function Example(SomeCell As String) As Integer

Example = Worksheet.Range("B1").Value * Worksheet.Range("C1").Value

End Function
```

Is there a way to tell Excel to update the function if cells "B1" and "C1" are changed? My understanding is it will only update if the cell in the argument changes.

Many thanks.

Edit: Essentially I want a way to manually add cells B1 and C1 to the dependency graph, as I don't want to include them as arguments to the function.

Comment: This function will do nothing unless you explicitly call it, unless it is referenced as a udf in a formula like `=Example(A1)`. It would only be triggered by a change in the cell in which that formula is contained and has nothing to do with A1 besides passing it as a parameter, which is never used and is superfluous. If you want to run some code when a change happens in a cell or range, then you would need to use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` but that is a subroutine, not a function, and can't return a value. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you want a function to be updated when a cell used in the calculation changes, include all of the ranges of interest as parameters to the function.   You could also consider `Application.Volatile` but that's less efficient.

Comment: @TimWilliams, both of those options are exactly what I was hoping to avoid. I was hoping for a way to manually add parameters to the dependency graph from within the VBA function, without having them as arguments to the function. For instance, a line of code adding B1 and C1 to the list of cells that the function is dependent on.

Comment: @JNevill what I mean is that the function is dependent on whichever cell 'SomeCell' is, but it's not dependent on cells B1 and C1 which are used from within the function. However, I'm hoping for a way to manually add B1 and C1 to the dependency graph, without having them as arguments to the function. This might not exist, but I'm hoping it does.

Comment: Cell events are one-and-done. There is no history of the events, so there won't be any dependency graph inherent to excel upon which you can map your function. A cell raises an event, which can be hooked into through the methods described. Tracking what events have fired and firing downstream events would have to built by hand. So if you want to have a function fire only after 3 cells have changed (beyond all of them experiencing change at the exact same time) you'll need to log when they change, and then check that log as new changes come through.

Comment: "the function is dependent on whichever cell 'SomeCell' is, but it's not dependent on cells B1 and C1 which are used from within the function" - it really seems from your description that the cell *is* dependent on B1 and C1.  Maybe you could explain *why* you don't want to add those cells as parameters.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is that I have a lookup function which 99% of the time is dependent on just a single cell. However, there a few extremely rare edge cases where this isn't the case. These edge cases require another function to execute which has more cells as inputs. So I was hoping to add these additional cells to the dependency graph only when these rare edge cases are executed, from within a VBA function. That way the main function won't be repeatedly executed whenever these additional mostly not-dependent cells are updated.

Comment: In that case using `Worksheet_Change` to detect changes in the "extra" cells and trigger recalculation of the cells in question seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking, but I'll try to make a suggestion.

Do you want to use your `Example` function in a worksheet or in VBA code? If in VBA code, the current cell values at the time of the call will be retrieved.

If it's in the worksheet, let's assume that in cell `B4` you call
`=Example(A1)`, while in cells `B1` and `C1` you have the numbers `2` and `3`.
Cell `B4` shows `6`. Now you change `B1` to `5` and would like the value in `B4` to update.
This can be invoked manually by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F9`.
If you want this to happen automatically, you can use an event macro that responds to a manual change in cells `B1` or `C1`, which macro must mark cell `B4` as `Dirty`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
      Range("B4").Dirty
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This feels very close to what I want, thank you. I have some questions. Can I set the current cell to dirty, without an explicit cell reference (i.e. not "B4")? If the function is nested in an IF statement and only sometimes executed, will it only be dirty when the condition is met and function executed, and otherwise be clean? For instance, IF(Z1=True,Example(A1),""). If I toggle Z1 between True and False will the dirty status be reset each time Example is executed?

Comment: I guess I still don't understand.
You can set any cell to the `Dirty` state, including `ActiveCell`, but it doesn't really make sense. 
A cell can be set `Dirty` only in the `Sub` routine and during its execution when the program encounters a `Range("B4").Dirty` interrupts the normal flow of the statements and immediately performs a recalculation of the formula in `B4`. Once this is done, the cell is no longer `Dirty` and the program executes further instructions.
I suggest that you be clearer about what you want to achieve, because we are passing each other a bit.